# Remote command execution over UART

Tags: remote, uart

I have connected my computer to the raspi over UART and was wondering if I could remotely execute a command. My intention is to log stats of my raspi CPU usage on my computer at specific intervals. I will be using a bash script which will loop repeatedly and pipe the output to a file.

I have tried looking at `cu` (callup) and `minicom` but have not found any solution.

Answer (score 2):

`cu -l /dev/device -s 115200` is the command you want to open a terminal over serial.

`dmesg | grep 'tty'` should tell you what device you want.

If this does not work you may want to check your RS232 wiring, especially make sure any port you are using is 3.3v compliant.

Comment: Full solution here. http://docs.freebsd.org/info/uucp/uucp.info.cu_Commands.html
use ~! and pass in command